# How can I catch WordPress custom settings page slug has already changed?

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-admin, admin

I created a custom settings page like below.

```php
    add_menu_page(
      __('Management', 'domain'),
      __('Management', 'domain'),
      'activate_plugins',
      'management', // <---
      function () {
        echo 'Hello';
      },
      'icon',
      999
    );
```

As we can see, this page is accessed via the "`admin.php?page=management`" link. I commented above with "`<---`"
But this is such a page that users can change this slug.

[image]

- For example, let's make this "`management-2`" and save the form.
- In this case, WordPress redirects to "`admin.php?page=management&settings-updated=true`", but since we set it to "`management-2`", I get a "`403`" error.
- At this point I need to catch a hook, start a new redirect and return it to the "`admin.php?page=management-2&settings-updated=true`" link, but I couldn't find any hook to do this.

Does anyone have any solution suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem you need to solve? If they edit your domain they'd also go to the wrong page. If they changed `/wp-admin` to `/ab-admin` they would also get the wrong page.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `admin_init` hook along with the `add_query_arg()` function to modify the redirection URL for handle the situation.

Redirect users to the correct URL `admin.php?page=management` if they access the settings page with an unexpected slug.

Modify the redirection URL after settings have been updated to include the current page slug `management`, ensuring that users have redirected back to the correct page `admin.php?page=management&settings-updated=true`

```
add_action('admin_init', 'check_custom_settings_page_redirect');

function check_custom_settings_page_redirect() {
    // Check if we are on the settings page and it's not the expected slug
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] !== 'management') {
        // Redirect to the correct URL with the updated slug
        $redirect_url = admin_url('admin.php?page=management');
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
        exit;
    }

    // Check if settings have been updated
    if (isset($_GET['settings-updated']) && $_GET['settings-updated'] === 'true') {
        // Modify the redirect URL to include the current page slug
        $redirect_url = add_query_arg(array('page' => 'management'), admin_url('admin.php'));
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
        exit;
    }
}
```